# How to order uploaded images by category using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I uploaded some images to a MySQL database using a simple form and some php.
The form has the following selection for catagory inputs.

```
<select name="image_ctgy">
<option value="animals">animals</option>
<option value="vegetables">vegetables</option>
<option value="minerals">minerals</option>
</select>
```

Each image has one of these categories in the MySQL table 'image_ctgy'.
Now I want to echo the images in the category animals to my webpage.

I use the following code to get all the images on my webpage:

```
<?php
/*** Check the $_GET variable ***/
   try    {
          /*** connect to the database ***/
          $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=;dbname=", '', '');

          /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
          $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          /*** The sql statement ***/
          $sql = "SELECT image_id, thumb_height, thumb_width, image_ctgy, image_type, image_name, title FROM testblob";

          /*** prepare the sql ***/
          $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

          /*** exceute the query ***/
          $stmt->execute(); 

          /*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
          $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

          /*** set the header for the image ***/
          foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $array)
              {
            echo '<div class="thumb" style="width: '.$array['thumb_width'].'px; height: '.$array['thumb_height'].'px;">
            <p class="title">' . $array["title"] . '</p>
            <p><a href="showfile.php?image_id='.$array['image_id'].'">
            <img src="showthumbs.php?image_id='.$array['image_id'].'" alt="'.$array['image_name'].' /">
            </a></p>
            </div>';

        }
   }
     catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
     catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

I think I need an if statement in the foreach loop to check if the image has to catagry Animals. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: you can change with query with WHERE clause : WHERE category = 'Animal'

Comment: That I didn't think of that myself.... Yes that works thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raveenanigam posted an awnser to my question.

you can change with query with WHERE clause : WHERE category = 'Animal'